# NEAT algorithm and dynamic topology neural networks

Tags: neural-networks

I have recently been investigating dynamic topology neural networks and there is only one problem I have with understanding them. Because a neuron could be inserted at any point, the neurons are no longer organised into layers, so how is it possible to ensure that all of the inputs for Neuron A at position X have been computed, prior to the computation of Neuron A's output, especially when each neurons output is calculated linearly? I am by no means experienced in the topic, just curious so any information would be helpful, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in neural net. But I recently read and answer [a question on NEAT](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69625/neuroevolution-neat-algorithm-innovation-numbers). From there, I would assume that direction of edges are already determined in each gene. Because of the way operations on genome was designed, I could see that you can ensure the genome is always in `topological order'.

Alternatively, looking at heuristic algorithms that iteratively update graph's weight as it learns (e.g. [pagerank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Iterative) and [ACO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms)), it should be fine to assume initial weight and just let the iteration stabilise. One could imagine this as every edge being directed both ways --- every link is both input and output.